# Load a text file from the specific line in matlab

Tags: matlab, text, load

I have a question relaetd to loading a text file in matlab. I have a text file with this format:

```
680
848
-0.1800 9.6535 -0.1719
 0.89435400 -0.44735900 -0.00047900
 0.44735900 0.89435400 0.00023400
 0.00032400 -0.00042300 1.00000000
 0.89435400 -0.44735900 -0.00047900 0.00000000
 0.44735900 0.89435400 0.00023400 0.00000000
 0.00032400 -0.00042300 1.00000000 0.00000000
 -0.1800    9.6535  -0.1719 0.0000
 -0.1800    9.6535  -0.1719 0.0000
 -0.1800    9.6535  -0.1719 0.0000
 -0.1800    9.6535  -0.1719 0.0000
 -0.1800    9.6535  -0.1719 0.0000
 -0.1800    9.6535  -0.1719 0.0000
 -0.1800    9.6535  -0.1719 0.0000
 -0.1800    9.6535  -0.1719 0.0000
 -0.1800    9.6535  -0.1719 0.0000
```

I want to load this text file from 10th line in matlab. Is there any way to load a text file from specific line in matlab? How can I do that?

cheers,

Comment: Read the documentation. Almost all of the [basic IO functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/text-files.html), like [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#namevaluepairarguments) and [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html#inputarg_R1), include header line parameters that allow you skip a certain number of lines.

Comment: @excaza, THX for reply. dlmread works fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to skip the lines while reading the file? You can also read in the whole file and then select all values without the first ten lines.

You could try this:

```
fileID = fopen('nameOfTextFile.txt');
formatSpec = '%s %s %s %s';
D = textscan(fileID,formatSpec, 'Delimiter','\t','CollectOutput',true);
datamatrix = D{1,1}(:,[1:4]);
skipped = datamatrix(11:end, 1:4)
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Not having sufficient rep to comment does not mean answer with your comment.

Comment: Sorry, that was indeed more a comment than an answer. I edited my answer.